# DOS batch removing last empty line in output TXT file

Tags: batch-file

The following code lists the files' names in a directory :

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b D:\folder\*.xml') do (
    echo %%a >> lines.txt
)
```

The result is (including lines numbers) :

```
1 86002_2014_1.xml 
2 86014_2014_1.xml 
3 86014_2014_2.xml 
4 86016_2014_1.xml 
5 86017_2014_1.xml
6
```

I always have an empty line at the end of any output TXT file from a Batch...

Is there a way to get a clean file without this line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of your command generates a set of lines, all terminated with an CRLF pair. This is the normal behaviour. `....text...0x0D0x0A`, the standard line termination in windows.

So, in your case, if there is another line or not is just a point of view. But, as for you, the last CRLF is not desired, it is necessary to discard the ending CRLF in all the lines (`<nul set /p ".=text"`) and convert them in an starting CRLF (`echo(`)

```dos
set "first="
<nul (for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b D:\folder\*.xml') do (
    if defined first (echo() else (set "first=1")
    set /p ".=%%a" 
)) > lines.txt
```